# Servicemix using Oracle ojdbc

Tags: oracle, apache-servicemix

I want to use jdbc directly in a project for service mix.
I have tried to install ojdbc7.jar with

bundle:install wrap:file:F:/tmp/ojdbc7.jar

after starting I get
264 | Active   |  80 | 0                                  | wrap_file_F__tmp_ojd
bc7.jar

My code is:

```
try (final Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl2", "bla", "bla")) {

            String sql = "Insert INTO message values('" + fall.getMessageid() + "','" + fall.getXml() + "')";
            final Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String msg = "Error while trying to persist Fall with msgid " + fall.getMessageid();
            log.error(msg, e);
            throw new AdvisException(msg, e);
        }
```

I get 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl2

Do I have to add some extra configuration or something?

edit:

I think I must import the installed bundle somehow in the MANIFEST.MF

Problem 1:

I have declared the dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>oracle-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and use

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5.3</version>
<extensions>true</extensions>
<configuration>
    <instructions>
        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
        <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
        <Private-Package>de.iteos</Private-Package>

    </instructions>
</configuration>
```

but the ojdbc6 does not show up the imports:

```
Import-Package: javax.jws,javax.xml.bind,javax.xml.bind.annotation,javax
 .xml.bind.annotation.adapters,javax.xml.datatype,javax.xml.namespace,ja
 vax.xml.parsers,javax.xml.transform,javax.xml.transform.stream,javax.xm
 l.ws,javax.xml.xpath,org.apache.activemq,org.apache.activemq.camel.comp
 onent,org.apache.camel;version="[2.16,3)",org.slf4j;version="[1.7,2)",o
 rg.w3c.dom,org.xml.sax
```

Why?

Problem 2:
the name of the bundle after the install is probably not compatible
How can I change this?

Comment: 1) Blind Insert 2) Concatenating SQL String instead of using parameters => Possible SQL Injection

Comment: I know, this is only for testing the stack, which does not work

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by copying the ojdbc driver to
apache-servicemix-7.0.1\lib\ext